# Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I've got an extension for all entities:

```
 public static class EntityBaseExtensions
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(this T item)
            where T : EntityBase
        {
            return item.EntityClone<T>();
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public virtual T EntityClone<T>() where T : EntityBase
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone() as T;
        }
```

but when i call it like:

```
 var details = user.Details.Clone();
```

i get

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for
>   which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

any ideas?

Comment: What is `user` what is `Details`? Is this line throwing exception `user.Details.Clone()` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, this line does. and user and details is just POCO entities, which mapped with `NHibernate` to database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is kinda weird:

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T item)
    where T : SimpleEntityBase
{
    return (T)item.EntityClone();
}
```

and

```
public virtual object EntityClone()
{
    return this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```